# if condition older with epoch date

Tags: bash, awk, epoch

I'm creating a condition that checks the actual date in epoch format and compares another string in epoch format; if the strings are more than 10 days old, do something...

i tried something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

timeago='10 days ago'
actual_date=$(date --date "now" +'%s')
last_seen_filter=$(date --date "$timeago" +'%s')
    
echo "INFO: actual_date=$actual_date, last_seen_filter=$last_seen_filter" >&2
    
if [ "$actual_date" -lt "$last_seen_filter" ]; then
        echo "something"
       else
        echo "do something"
fi
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
cutoff=$(date -d '10 days ago' +%s)
key="1624684050 1624688000"
while read -r "$key" 
do
  age=$(date -d "now" +%s)
  if (($age < $cutoff))
  then
    printf "Warning! key %s is older than 10 days\n" "$key" >&2
  fi
done < input
```

That's not enough for what I need, I have epoch dates in a file called `converted_data`, i need to include this strings on if comparision.

```
1624684050
1634015250
1614661650
1622005650
```

Comment: You have really weird spacing errors, perhaps try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.

Comment: But what is your actual question here? How do these numbers relate to your code? (And there are still multiple spacing errors.)

Comment: Do **really** need the comparison to be 10 calendar days (where you need to check for locale, timezone, leap days, leap seconds, daylight savings, etc.) or is a comparison of `10 * 24 * 60 * 60 seconds` good enough?

Comment: @EdMorton I'm trying to create a locale check, how to calc epoch date in string to actual_date, something like this, if epoch_date is older(10 days) than actual_date, my doubt is how to calc epoch date, any materials help's me!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "epoch date". Do you mean you're trying to convert epoch seconds in your current locale to the equivalent date in that same locale (affected by DST, etc. in that locale) and then compare 2 such dates to see if they're 10 days apart or something else?

Comment: @EdMorton yep, something like this, i'm looking for alternatives, and all of them we're welcome!

Comment: OK, then [edit] your question to a) fix the issues in the code you posted (copy/paste it into http://shellcheck.net as @tripleee suggested and it'll tell you about the bugs) and b) include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input **and expected output** so we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do but maybe this with GNU awk will get you started:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { today=strftime("%F") }
    {
        secs = $0
        days = 0
        date = strftime("%F",secs)
        while ( strftime("%F",secs+=(24*60*60)) < today ) {
            ++days
        }
        print $0":", date, "->", today, "=", days
    }
' file
1624684050: 2021-06-26 -> 2021-06-13 = 0
1634015250: 2021-10-12 -> 2021-06-13 = 0
1614661650: 2021-03-01 -> 2021-06-13 = 102
1622005650: 2021-05-26 -> 2021-06-13 = 17
```

The `0`s for future dates are because you only asked about 10-days past dates so I don't care to adapt for both past and future deltas. I also didn't put much thought into it so check the logic and the math!

Comment: wow, this helped me so much, you are the guy!
Thank you sir!